# Suppressing INFO messages for Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, log4j, log4j2

I am looking for a solution for suppressing the INFO messages with Hibernate.  I tried the instructions given in the following Stackoverflow post, but to no avail:
[Hibernate suppress info messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723030/hibernate-suppress-info-messages)

My output continues to spit out the INFO messages, despite implementing the suggested change.

---

I am using Eclipse as my IDE and I have a Maven parent project, with multiple child module projects.

Previously I did not have a `log4j.properties` file in my project but now I have created one, at the same location where I have my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file i.e. `src/test/resources` of the child Maven module.

The contents of my `log4j.properties` file are as follows:

```
# Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723030/hibernate-suppress-info-messages
#rootlogger specs
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

---

Following the tip from @TestoTestini, I added `log4j` as a dependency in my child Maven module pom.xml.  It was only after that step that the `log4j.properties` file that I had added earlier seemed to take effect.  However, I am still working on suppressing the messages with the Hibernate tag.

Answer (score 1):

I think now you have now to add the configuration for Hibernate, I use

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=WARN
# use this to not see the [deprecated DTD] message from Hibernate 
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.orm.deprecation=ERROR
# use this to not see the "no cache configuration" warning
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory=ERROR
# This is very important, otherwise db creation errors go silent
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=DEBUG
```

ah I see now you already use ERROR as root logger level so maybe your configuration file is not being read, which version of Hibernate are you using ?

Maybe you have an other log library in the classpath like JBoss LogManager or Log4j 2 ? In that case they might be picked up in place of Log4j